# Covering number of a single-layer neural network with Lipschitz Function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am interested in determining the covering number of a 1-layered neural network with a Lipschitz function $\sigma~:~\mathbb{R}^{d} \to [0,1]^{d}$ of Lipschitz constant **1**. That is, consider a function space

$\mathcal{A} = \Big[{a(x) = \sigma(Wx + b)~:~\|W\|_{F} \leq 1, \|b_{0}\|_{2} \leq 1, W \in  \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{d}})\Big] $

Find covering number $N(\mathcal{A}, \mu, \epsilon)$ where $\mu$ is the $L_{2}$ norm. Assume $X \in [-1,1]^{d}$.

Furthermore, would it it be possible to generalize this to a multi-layer neural network?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer, but I would like to know, why is this kind of problem interesting? Are there applications?
I really need to know this.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

See this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08498 for a solution, which introduces a covering bound on matrix-matrix products together with an inductive technique to combine covers of layers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342102)